# font-size is larger on the content part of site. How to fix it?

Tags: html, css

Display of my website is wrong on the mobile devices (for example samsung galaxy s 3) url: http://smapse.ru. Text part in class .quote-text is larger than menu on the left. Desktop devices display is fine. I tried to fix it with different font-size values but that brought no result. Please advise me what is wrong in html/css? Thanks!

screenshot from phone http://postimg.org/image/k85gyo0qd

While the page is loading, font size is actually normal. When my page is loaded on device the text becomes larger.

**RESOLVED**
I added to the css in the end:

```
html {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  font-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

that fixed the problem for text adjusting in the right part of my site on iphone.
Web-kit has a bug. I added max-height: 999999px; to the element to fix that problem.

Comment: Try using 'em' values in place of px.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: You can see all css on site. It is very large to post it here.

Comment: I tried to set 1em text on the left and 1em text on the right. And text on the right is larger

Answer (score 0):

On the left, div class title has font size 16, labels below it have 14, and your .quote-text has 17. And it is all the same on desktop and mobiles, so your quote-text is always bigger than menu fonts on the left. You might just not notice it on desktop.

To change title text in menu, use class: `.b-left-search-form .title`
To change small labels in left menu use: `.b-left-search-form .checkboxes label`
And to change .quote-text use: `.quote-text > div`

Comment: Sorry but I have it actual size in time of page loading. When my page is loaded on device text become larger. Here I post image from my phone http://postimg.org/image/k85gyo0qd/